# Filebeat buffer control

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am running filebeat on a machine streaming 2GB data. While streaming the buffer size of the machine is slowly increasing to 100-2000MB(filling all memory).

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-31-xx-09:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3943         176        2163           0        1603        3552
Swap:             0           0           0
```

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  tags: ["gunicorn"]
  paths:
    - "/home/ubuntu/data/gunicorn.log"

- type: log
  tags: ["apache"]
  paths:
    - "/home/ubuntu/data/access.log"

queue.mem:
  events: 8000
  flush.min_events: 512
  flush.timeout: 2s

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["xxx.xx.xxx.86:5044"]
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @ibexit Can we fixed maximum buffer/queue size (in memory) for filebeat ?

Comment: Maybe you are running into a memory leak. What version of Filebeat are you running? Have a look at this recently fixed issue: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/9302

Comment: @SiddharthKumar have You figured out the solution?

Comment: @MichałDygas https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-internal-queue.html